# Using the timestamp(0) data type in PostgreSQL

Tags: type-conversion, database-migration

I am migrating a database from Oracle to PostgreSQL.
I am considerting using the timestamp(0) data type in PostgreSQL for the date data type in Oracle.
But I came accross a Don't Do List.

https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_timestamp.280.29_or_timestamptz.280.29

The above post says:

> **Don't use timestamp(0) or timestamptz(0)**
>
> Don't use a precision specification, especially not 0, for timestamp
> columns or casts to timestamp.
>
> Use `date_trunc('second', blah)` instead.
>
> **Why not?**
>
> Because it rounds off the fractional part rather than truncating it as
> everyone would expect. This can cause unexpected issues; consider that
> when you store now() into such a column, you might be storing a value
> half a second in the future.
>
> **When should you?**
>
> Never.

I wonder if using the timestamp(0) data type is acceptable.
And I also want to know how others are migrating the DATE data type in Oracle.

Comment: I guess the point the wiki tries to make is that having something like `1999-12-31 23:59:59.560001` imported as `2000-01-01 00:00:00` is not a desirable outcome. I suppose that people import dates without altering them.